# Is there a Quick Search Tool in IntelliJ iDEA?

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, spring-tool-suite, quick-search

In STS (Spring Tool Suite) version, We have this quick search plugin (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>) that quickly spawns a dialog box that progressively displays all found occurences of the text provided in the project. Is there such thing in IntelliJ IDEA?

A good description of the plugin can be found here:
http://spring.io/blog/2013/07/11/eclipse-quick-search

Comment: I was actually talking about text searches and not file search. Well I know ctrl+shift+f does the job but this plugin that I mentioned is more superior than that. Please visit link. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use shortcut key: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>. You have to press double shift button

Comment: Sorry. I think Ctrl + Shift + F is suitable for your idea

Comment: Well I think that's the closest I can really get. The Eclipse counterpart of that is Ctrl + H but it's slow while this plugin I'm talking about, the quick search, is very fast in searching it can be used in navigating files provided that you can recall a unique text in it. It doesn't show a progress dialog box. It just lists all closest occurences one after another until it lists all possible occurences.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following shortcuts for helping you to navigate throughout your code:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>  - Search for classes

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> - Search for file name

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> - Search for symbol name

Using a mixture of those you'll be able to find places in your program.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>

Allows you to search within the path

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> brings up the "Search Anywhere" popup

Comment: Do any of these actually search the contents of the source code? For example, if I've defined the variable:
`private String hello = "Hello world!"`

I can find this exact line of could by opening the STS quick search and typing `ello w`. IntelliJ does not seem to have this level of search or maybe I just don't have it configured right...

Answer (score 2):

I want this feature too, and it's not quite there, but could be.

The best you can do is to train your fingers as follows:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- type your search text
- If the preview tab isn't showing, do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Page Down</kbd>

The problem is that you can't open just the file that you want, unless, you type enough that there is only one match which will open if you select:

- Options: Result options: Skip results tab when only one occurrence is found

This will open the file instead of showing the results

It's also handy to set up `File mask(s)` to only the files that are relevant to you (for example for me I want results in *.ts* (for Typescript including TSX, but not .js)

Comment: This is as close as we get. I honestly prefer SSTS to IntelliJ and this is a big reason why (but I'm forced to use the latter because of lackluster support for Grails)

Answer (score 0):

"Find in Path" is probably what you're looking for. It is probably bound to <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> or <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>, depending on your key bindings and whether you are on Mac / Windows / or Linux. It can also be found under the "Edit", "Find" menu.

Answer (score 0):

The thing that makes quick search in eclipse so awesome is the snappy as-you-type result feedback.

You can get this in intellij w/ `ctrl+shift+f` or `cmd+shift+f` as others mentioned, but to truly emulate the eclipse quick search plugin you will want to **switch to the Preview tab** (in version 15, anyway).